# append time difference values in a list

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi

I am using Raspberry pi with python for a project and i am also a beginner to Python.
I have  tried this code  in Spyder IDE in windows and it was working fine but now  i am  facing the error for the same in raspberry pi inbuilt python IDE. I know that i made a small mistake somewhere but unfortunately, i could not find. Can someone please help me to rectify?

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = list(range(150))

t=[]


str_time = time.time()
for x in range(150):
   time.sleep(0.001)
   t.append((time.time() - str_time))

y= [x * 1000 for x in t]
plt.plot(y,a)
plt.show()
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: you have used time.time in image ( not used `()`), that's why it is giving error there, but here this code is working fine

Comment: Thanks... it works fine